# Iframe points to secure. sub-domain, but it never had an SSL certificate?

Tags: facebook

### Background

I am working on something set up by an old developer who is unreachable. He set up an iframe in a tab page in Facebook, which points to the address secure.*****.co.uk/*person*. The link is no longer working and I'm trying to fix it.

In file manager, in the httpdocs of the site the *person* folder exists but is empty. I believe at some point it had a file that contained a portal to a booking site, a contact form and some hard-coded opening times. *(I'm not sure how to set this up atm, but if someone could point me to a tutorial I would be grateful)*

### Issue

As I understand, to have an iframe you require an SSL certificate however the domain it points to never had one. The website is around a year and a half old, but we have only just noticed the iframe to not be working.

I'm confused as to the necessity of the SSL as it is required but somehow it worked without. Apologies if what I'm saying is wrong as I don't have much experience with Facebook apps.

Comment: You need SSL to get your app displayed inside the Facebook iframe, yes – because facebook.com is served via HTTPS to all users nowadays (that used to be different), so the browser would block the iframe content as insecure if it was loaded via HTTP and not HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I understood from my research, but I'm confused why it used to work even without SSL, I'm trying to find when facebook started forcing the use of SSL (I think 2011)

Comment: It was still possible for some time after that to manually opt-out of browsing Facebook via HTTPS; so your previous developer might have done that, or perhaps used a self-signed certificate for testing … or they might even have developed the script under a completely different address and only changed the setting inside the app later.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everything that made the facebook app work had disappeared without a trace. These are the steps I took to fix it?

1. Created the app in FB develoment and pointed it to secure.domain.com/fbapp
2. Added an SSL certificate via plesk to the domain
3. Added the html app code to index.html in secure.domain.com/fbapp and it loaded in facebook just fine